# ASP.NET MySQL.NET connection string

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I have an ASP.NET page that uses the MySQL.NET library to access a MySQL DB on the server. My question is about storing the connection string in the web.config. The MySQL.NET connection string looks like:

"server=localhost;user=user;database=db;password=pw"

I have to assume having the pw in the web.config as plain text isn't a good thing. What are my options to getting around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encrypt the connection string in your web.config.

For more information : [Securing Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: So I basically make a separate program, that will take the config file and encrypt/decrypt it? Then in my asp.net page I decrypt it before reading? "The connection string can only be decrypted on the computer on which it was encrypted." This seems interesting. So I would have to do this on the web server itself when I'm ready to deploy it into production then? So hosts that don't allow you to have direct access to the server machine, I'd have to do this in the asp.net page 1 time when I put it on the server? Seems kind of strange. What if the host switches servers on me at some point?

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt Web.config using "Protected Configuration". See here on MSDN for a full overview of the process:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky(v=vs.100).aspx